Why does my SwiftUI app crash when opened from an intent?
I'm encountering a crash in my SwiftUI app when it is opened via an AppIntent. The app runs perfectly when launched by tapping the app icon, but it crashes when opened from an intent.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
import AppIntents
import SwiftUI

@main
struct GOGODemoApp: App {
  @State
  private var state: MyController = MyController()
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      MyView()
        //.environment(state) // ok
    }
    .environment(state) // failed to start app, crash with 'Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread'
  }
}

struct MyView: View {
  @Environment(MyController.self) var stateController
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello")
  }
}

@Observable
public class MyController {
}

struct OpenIntents: AppIntent {
  static var title: LocalizedStringResource = "OpenIntents"
  static var description = IntentDescription("Open App from intents.")
  static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = true

  @MainActor
  func perform() async throws -> some IntentResult {
    return .result()
  }
}

Observations:
The app works fine when launched by tapping the app icon.
The app crashes when opened via an AppIntent.
The app works if I inject the environment in MyView instead of in WindowGroup.
Question: Why does injecting the environment in WindowGroup cause the app to crash when opened from an intent, but works fine otherwise? What is the difference when injecting the environment directly in MyView?
Below is the crash report:
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: C10F1A06-CC21-4AC1-93C4-F9C8AEE09207
CrashReporter Key:   AB420CD3-BAFD-0A50-15C1-C41324917ACD
Hardware Model:      Mac14,3
Process:             GOGODemo [22403]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/99106351-788D-4605-A5E6-475AD73ED05C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/ABA85B92-BB92-45C5-BFCD-CB507176D9D0/GOGODemo.app/GOGODemo
Identifier:          com.gogodjzhu.GOGODemo
Version:             1.0 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [16220]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.99106351-788D-4605-A5E6-475AD73ED05C [8765]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [1043]

Date/Time:           2024-07-19 22:58:49.2614 +0800
Launch Time:         2024-07-19 22:58:49.0411 +0800
OS Version:          macOS 14.5 (23F79)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001929f3938
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process: exc handler [22403]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x1929f3938 _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 248
1   SwiftUI                                0x1c5794b14 0x1c4371000 + 21117716
2   SwiftUI                                0x1c51f27e4 0x1c4371000 + 15210468
3   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x192ad2ce8 RawKeyPathComponent._projectReadOnly<A, B, C>(_:to:endingWith:) + 532
4   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x192ad2758 closure #2 in KeyPath._projectReadOnly(from:) + 496
5   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x192ad24a8 KeyPath._projectReadOnly(from:) + 248
6   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x192ad539c swift_getAtKeyPath + 20
7   SwiftUI                                0x1c4d6ab10 0x1c4371000 + 10459920
8   SwiftUI                                0x1c4a5cafc 0x1c4371000 + 7256828
9   SwiftUI                                0x1c4a5c42c 0x1c4371000 + 7255084
10  SwiftUI                                0x1c586c6e0 0x1c4371000 + 22001376
11  SwiftUI                                0x1c586c71c 0x1c4371000 + 22001436
12  libswiftCore.dylib                     0x192adba04 withUnsafePointer<A, B>(to:_:) + 20
13  libswiftCore.dylib                     0x192c862ac withUnsafeMutablePointer<A, B>(to:_:) + 12
14  SwiftUI                                0x1c586c5a4 0x1c4371000 + 22001060
15  SwiftUI                                0x1c586c34c 0x1c4371000 + 22000460
16  SwiftUI                                0x1c5374abc 0x1c4371000 + 16792252
17  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2bdc75c AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 504
18  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2bdceec AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 432
19  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2be4e90 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, unsigned char&, long) + 716
20  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2bfbd24 AGGraphGetValue + 232
21  SwiftUI                                0x1c4c053c4 0x1c4371000 + 8995780
22  SwiftUI                                0x1c48ca814 0x1c4371000 + 5609492
23  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2bdc75c AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 504
24  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2bdceec AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 432
25  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2be4e90 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, unsigned char&, long) + 716
26  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2bfbd24 AGGraphGetValue + 232
27  SwiftUI                                0x1c5161e80 0x1c4371000 + 14618240
28  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2bdc75c AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 504
29  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2bdceec AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 432
30  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2be4e90 AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, AG::AttributeID, unsigned int, unsigned int, AGSwiftMetadata const*, unsigned char&, long) + 716
31  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2bfbd24 AGGraphGetValue + 232
32  SwiftUI                                0x1c465048c 0x1c4371000 + 3011724
33  SwiftUI                                0x1c48ac2b4 0x1c4371000 + 5485236
34  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2bdc75c AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 504
35  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2bdceec AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, unsigned int) + 432
36  AttributeGraph                         0x1b2bea8dc AG::Subgraph::update(unsigned int) + 828
37  SwiftUI                                0x1c4f2df70 0x1c4371000 + 12308336
38  SwiftUI                                0x1c57e6e54 0x1c4371000 + 21454420
39  SwiftUI                                0x1c57e4e5c 0x1c4371000 + 21446236
40  SwiftUI                                0x1c49c72c8 0x1c4371000 + 6644424
41  SwiftUI                                0x1c58412f4 0x1c4371000 + 21824244
42  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18016b4f4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
43  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18016cd3c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
44  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18017bb24 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1272
45  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18017b61c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 40
46  CoreFoundation                         0x1803f1a30 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
47  CoreFoundation                         0x1803ec148 __CFRunLoopRun + 1936
48  CoreFoundation                         0x1803eb5a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
49  GraphicsServices                       0x18e9fbae4 GSEventRunModal + 160
50  UIKitCore                              0x1852f02e4 -[UIApplication _run] + 868
51  UIKitCore                              0x1852f3f5c UIApplicationMain + 124
52  SwiftUI                                0x1c51fc1b0 0x1c4371000 + 15249840
53  SwiftUI                                0x1c51fc050 0x1c4371000 + 15249488
54  SwiftUI                                0x1c4f02fa4 0x1c4371000 + 12132260
55  GOGODemo                               0x100245f54 static GOGODemoApp.$main() + 40
56  GOGODemo                               0x100247268 main + 12 (GOGODemoApp.swift:14)
57  dyld_sim                               0x1003e5544 start_sim + 20
58  dyld                                   0x1005e60e0 start + 2360


Can you post the actual crash stack? Posting the name of the thread doesn't give any insight into why it's crashing

May be the answer to this question can help you to find the problem .

Since your controller is an object and App is only init once try changing @State var to let.  Usually controllers are structs btw. And non optional @State is only for values or structs. It’s @StateObject for non optional classes.
